# My pkg file on Mac OSX can't install successfully

Tags: macos

I used **xcodebuild -scheme my_scheme /app_location**  command to build .app 
and then I used **pkgbuild --identifier my_identifer --root my_app --component-plist  my_app_plist  /pkg_location**

I opened the .pkg and began installation steps, after installing I found that I couldn't find the application in **Finder**. It means that the app was not installed successfully.

I also use terminal to :/Application , and I can't find my app in Application folder.

What did I miss??

Comment: My OS is OSX 10.11

Comment: Check the logs in the Console app, under installer (/var/log/installer)